# How to make python class "ast.literal_eval()" compatible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree, pyro

I have my custom class that represents an object.
I want to make that object compatible with "ast.literal_eval()"

How can I do that? I can add necessary method/code to my class if necessary.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` evaluates literals. Python does not support user defined literals. Ergo, you can't use `ast.literal_eval` to produce a user defined type. If you could, all the security guarantees of `ast.literal_eval` would go out the window.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. You will need to reimplement it from scratch, adding support for your class within it.

Comment: my question is how can i add that support to my class?

Comment: You cannot. `ast.literal_eval()` chooses what it accepts.

Answer (score 1):

Because you tagged your question with Pyro, I assume you're asking it in the context of serializing your own classes when using Pyro's remote method calls. Pyro provides [a mechanism to do that](http://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/clientcode.html#changing-the-way-your-custom-classes-are-de-serialized).